# Testing angular forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing

I am trying to test an angular app in protrator and I do not understand something.
 I put this line there

```html
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });
```

And I want to refenrence the elements of an HTML form using this line:

```html
fdescribe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

  var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
  
  ...and test its result
```

In protractor we do not put the test files corresponding to a specific .ts file in its folder, so this test searches in the whole project for an id **gobutton**  or it searches for an id **gobutton** that belongs specifically to the link that I have put on browser.get()??

And my next question is if the page I wanna test requires a login, can I just use browser.get url of this page and test the elements or I should do the part of logging during my test?

And is it normal if my browser closes itself afterexecuting one test, or it should stay opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot of questions ;)

- Protractor will search the whole DOM for the element's id. Even if you work with the mentioned *.po.ts files in the component folders, they'll eventually only deliver the elements id represented by a string you then search via `element(by.id())`.
- If a login is required, you'll have to consider it during your test. I doubt that you can bypass the login mechanism, except the login can be switched off on the testing stage and switched on on the production stage.
- Yes, it is the standard behavior of Protractor to close the browser after having finished the test. This is because you have your protocol file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! How do I see the resuts in the seleniumServer if it closes itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my protractor.conf.js looks like. The given path `target` is located on the level of `/src`.

```
let HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

// always create test-report.html, screen shots only in case of failures
let reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/test-screenshots',
  filename: 'test-report.html',
  reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
  pathBuilder: function (currentSpec, suites, browserCapabilities) {
    // will return chrome/your-spec-name.png
    return browserCapabilities.get('browserName') + '/' + currentSpec.fullName;
  }
});

exports.config = {

...

    beforeLaunch: function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
      });
    }
```

Comment: This is the important config block in your protractor.conf.js. Here you define where the report is put at and under which circumstances.

Comment: And how can I disable this logging part? If I wanna enter directly in a form but without logging in?

Comment: Sorry mate, but this is not doable with Protractor. This has to be done by your developers. They have to implement a kind of a switch that detects on which stage the App you wanna test is currently running on. And according to this the login page is mandatory or not.